# Estimates for zeta in holomorphic neighbourhood

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, estimation

I´m working on a book for my seminar in the university and I am stuck in the argumentation of one Theorem.

So the Theorem says Zeta has no zeta in $\sigma>1$.

To proof we say $\zeta(1+i\tau_0)=0$, so $\tau_0$ can´t be $0$ and $zeta$ is holomorphic in some neighbourhood of $1+i\tau_0$. Therefore

$\zeta(\sigma+i\tau_0)\ll\sigma-1~~~(\sigma>1)$

on the other hand

$\zeta(\sigma)\ll(\sigma-1)^{-1},~\zeta(\sigma+2i\tau_0)\ll 1~~~~(\sigma>1)$

the rest of the proof is quite clear for me, but where do these three estimates come from? Anyone got a clue?

Comment: You don't assume $\zeta(1+i\tau_0)=1$, you assume $\zeta(1+i\tau_0)=0$. But since $\zeta(s)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$,  it cannot have a zero there, so $\tau_0 \neq 0$. I am not sure what exactly your problem is, but if you do understand the proof, you must know that it relies on a trigonometric inequality. Just google zero-free region of the zeta function.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a mistype.
My problem is, that I don´t know, where the estimates after the "Therefore" and "on the other hand" came from.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that the functions $\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1), \frac{\zeta(\sigma + i\tau_0)}{\sigma-1}$ and $\zeta(\sigma + 2i\tau_0)$ are bounded as $\sigma \to 1^+$.

Since $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$, the function $\zeta(s)(s-1)$ is holomorphic at $s=1$, and therefore $\zeta(\sigma)(\sigma-1)$ is bounded as $\sigma \to 1^+$.

Now $\zeta(1+ i\tau_0) = 0$, so again by holomorphicity $$\frac{\zeta(\sigma + i\tau_0)}{\sigma-1} = \frac{\zeta(\sigma + i\tau_0) - \zeta(1 + i\tau_0)}{(\sigma + i\tau_0)-(1+i\tau_0)}$$ 
is bounded as $\sigma \to 1^+$.

And finally $\zeta(\sigma + 2i\tau_0)$ converges to $\zeta(1+ 2i\tau_0)$ as $\sigma \to 1^+$, so it is also bounded.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1232462)

Comment: (it is bounded because $\zeta(s)(s-1)$ is analytic at $s=1$, or just because $|\zeta(s)| \le 1+\frac1{\sigma-1}$)

Comment: @TheCount Sorry about that. I edited it.